# Disable rewrite of html_tag?

Tags: 8, meta-tags

In my module

```
    function hook_page_attachments(array &$page) {

      $og_image = array(
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
          'property' => 'og:image',
          'content' =>   'http://example.com/pic.php?id=839813.jpg&size=300',
        ),
      );


      $page['#attached']['html_head'][] =  [$og_image, 'og:image'];
}
```

On the page the results look like this

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/pic.php?id=839813.jpg&amp;size=300" />
```

The & is replaced for html use. Can I avoid that or added meta tags in another way?

Answer (score 0):

I build a workaround. I created a custom path in drupal that redirect to the external image url like /image/{img-id} . If anyone find an answer on the main question please post.